# Join tables when one column has a prefix

Tags: mysql, select

This is my "product" table `WHERE sku RLIKE 'IP-205-1067-16' or sku IN ('205-d-SC55G','205-d-RC099G','205-d-SC45G','205-d-RC099G')`:

```
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|            sku            | price_1 | full_color_imprint_id | embroidery_imprint_id | screen_print_imprint_id | laser_engraving_imprint_id |
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| IP-205-1067-16            | 1.55556 | NULL                  | NULL                  | 63276                   | 32539                      |
| IP-205-1067-16-39423495   | 1.55556 | NULL                  | NULL                  | 63276                   | 32539                      |
| IP-205-1067-16-1272347    | 1.55556 | NULL                  | NULL                  | 63276                   | 32539                      |
| IP-205-1067-16-56185      | 1.55556 | NULL                  | NULL                  | 63276                   | 32539                      |
| IP-205-1067-16-1706399150 | 1.55556 | NULL                  | NULL                  | 63276                   | 32539                      |
| 205-d-SC45G               | 45      | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL                    | NULL                       |
| 205-d-SC55G               | 55      | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL                    | NULL                       |
| 205-d-RC059G              | 0.59    | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL                    | NULL                       |
| 205-d-RC099G              | 0.99    | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL                    | NULL                       |
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

This is my "imprint_locations" table `WHERE imprint_method_id IN (63276,32539)`:

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|   id   | imprint_method_id |    name    |  setup_sku  | running_sku  |
+--------+-------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 809128 |             32539 | Body Right | 205-d-SC45G | 205-d-RC059G |
| 809129 |             32539 | Body Left  | 205-d-SC45G | 205-d-RC059G |
| 808288 |             63276 | Body Right | 205-d-SC55G | 205-d-RC099G |
| 808289 |             63276 | Body Left  | 205-d-SC55G | 205-d-RC099G
+--------+-------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

This is the end result I'm trying to achieve:

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|            sku            | embroidery_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1 | embroidery_imprint_id_running_sku_price_1 | screen_print_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1 | screen_print_imprint_id_running_sku_price_1 | laser_engraving_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1 | laser_engraving_imprint_id_running_sku_price_1 |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| IP-205-1067-16            | NULL                                    | NULL                                      |                                        55 | 0.99                                        |                                           45 | 0.59                                           |
| IP-205-1067-16-39423495   | NULL                                    | NULL                                      |                                        55 | 0.99                                        |                                           45 | 0.59                                           |
| IP-205-1067-16-1272347    | NULL                                    | NULL                                      |                                        55 | 0.99                                        |                                           45 | 0.59                                           |
| IP-205-1067-16-56185      | NULL                                    | NULL                                      |                                        55 | 0.99                                        |                                           45 | 0.59                                           |
| IP-205-1067-16-1706399150 | NULL                                    | NULL                                      |                                        55 | 0.99                                        |                                           45 | 0.59                                           |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see that the product table has screen_print_imprint_id which matches the imprint_method_id in the imprint_locations table.

Comment: `WHERE imprint_locations.setup_sku = CONCAT('setup_sku_', product.sku)`

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Hey Barmar, ABC and setup sku ABC are fictitious. I have a product.sku called he-123-h100 and a imprint_locations.setup_sku called 924-gee.

Comment: Then your question isn't clear. How are those two SKUs supposed to be relalated to each other?

Comment: You also haven't said what you're trying to do with these two tables. I assumed you were trying to join them based on the similar SKUs.

Comment: In the last line I say what I'm looking for. In bold. 

I need to most likely create a temporary table then use that table against the original table. 

So connect and create the temp product&imprint_locations table. Then take that and get the product.price_1 of the imprint_locations.setup_sku where imprint_locations.imprint_method_id=product.full_color_imprint_id. 

I'm not sure. 

Basically I want to display the product.sku and the product.sku's product.full_color_imprint_id's imprint_location.imprint_id's imprint_locations.setup_sku's product.price_1

Comment: If you can share the relations as output of the tables containing sample data instead of explaining the relationships in words, things will be more clear. Also please share the expected output with the sample data.

Comment: @AniketV - I've added the tables containing sample data.

Comment: @Barmar - Hopefully the added tables will help. I appreciate your work.

Comment: How do you decide whether to use `Body Right` or `Body Left` to link the rows? In your example they both link to the same rows, but I assume that isn't always the case.

Comment: @Barmar Body Right and Body Left are actually not useful and should've been left out... They are just locations to put the screen print or laser engraving and they will change. Not sure if I need to explain something more?

Comment: But there are two rows in `imprint_locations` for each `imprint_method_id`. Which one should be used to link to the `product` table to get the price for the `running_sku` and `setup_sku`?

Comment: I guess it should be grouped by `imprint_method_id` because I only need one of them. Sometimes there are 5 duplicate ids in that column because there are 5 different locations. Does this help?

Comment: But what if they link to different `running_sku` or `setup_sku`, which one should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with the `product` table twice, using the `imprint_locations` table as an intermediate relation table.

You could use a separate join for each ID field you want to link, or you can use a method from [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) to join once and pivot the prices into the appropriate columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.sku, 
    MAX(IF(p1.embroidery_imprint_id = l.imprint_method_id AND p2.sku = l.setup_sku, p2.price_1, NULL)) AS embroidery_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1,
    MAX(IF(p1.embroidery_imprint_id = l.imprint_method_id AND p2.sku = l.running_sku, p2.price_1, NULL)) AS embroidery_imprint_id_running_sku_price_1,
    MAX(IF(p1.screen_print_imprint_id = l.imprint_method_id AND p2.sku = l.setup_sku, p2.price_1, NULL)) AS screen_print_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1,
    MAX(IF(p1.screen_print_imprint_id = l.imprint_method_id AND p2.sku = l.running_sku, p2.price_1, NULL)) AS screen_print_imprint_id_running_sku_price_1,
    MAX(IF(p1.laser_engraving_imprint_id = l.imprint_method_id AND p2.sku = l.setup_sku, p2.price_1, NULL)) AS laser_engraving_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1,
    MAX(IF(p1.laser_engraving_imprint_id = l.imprint_method_id AND p2.sku = l.running_sku, p2.price_1, NULL)) AS laser_engraving_imprint_id_running_sku_price_1
FROM product AS p1
JOIN imprint_locations AS l ON l.imprint_method_id IN (p1.embroidery_imprint_id, p1.screen_print_imprint_id, p1.laser_engraving_imprint_id)
JOIN product AS p2 ON p2.sku IN (l.running_sku, l.setup_sku)
GROUP BY p1.sku
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27c9e1/1)

Comment: I see it works in your demo, but it simply keeps timing out when I try and run it. :( Thanks for your efforts. I'm not sure what to do about it. Maybe I should just get one at a time? embroidery_imprint_id_setup_sku_price_1 then export it... then get imprint_method_id_setup_sku_price_1 then export it...

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the columns being used in the `ON` clauses.

Comment: I have indexed every single column. It still runs and won't complete. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You might have to split it up into separate `LEFT JOIN`s for each column that you're joining on. It's not complicated, just very verbose for all those combinations.

Comment: I couldn't use your statement, but it does work so I'm giving you the correct answer. Thanks for your time.